# Very long loading with parse NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing

I've set up a UILabel, which gets its content from parse.com. All worked fine, until I enabled fly mode. At the view which loads the label I get very long loading time and the console gives me that code:

```
    2012-11-08 21:07:41.179 My App[5275:907] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2012-11-08 21:07:41.231 My App[5275:907] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet." UserInfo=0x1e5c2f00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet., NSUnderlyingError=0x1e5c1d70 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.14)
2012-11-08 21:07:41.232 My App[5275:907] Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.287663 seconds.
2012-11-08 21:07:42.582 My App[5275:907] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet." UserInfo=0x1e5c6f00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet., NSUnderlyingError=0x1e5c6f40 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.14)
2012-11-08 21:07:42.583 My App[5275:907] Network connection failed. Making attempt 3 after sleeping for 2.575326 seconds.
2012-11-08 21:07:45.215 My App[5275:907] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet." UserInfo=0x1f88bd90 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f88c840 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.14)
2012-11-08 21:07:45.216 My App[5275:907] Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 5.150652 seconds.
2012-11-08 21:07:50.383 My App[5275:907] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet." UserInfo=0x1f88c310 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f88b4a0 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.14)
2012-11-08 21:07:50.384 My App[5275:907] Network connection failed. Making attempt 5 after sleeping for 10.301305 seconds.
2012-11-08 21:08:00.743 My App[5275:907] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet." UserInfo=0x1e5c8160 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f88e450 "Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.14)
```

"Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet" means that theres no connection to the internet.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do networking on the main thread - ever :)

**dispatch_async** a block and only set the label's text on the main thread.

```
- (void)doLongOperation:(id)someParam withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *newLabelString))completionHandler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSString *labelString = /*do call to parse OR any other long running operation*/

        if ( completionHandler ) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(labelString); 
        });
    });
}

// now in your main app call it
[self doLongOperation:nil /*we dont need anything here*/ withCompletionHandler:^(NSString *newLabelString) {
    self.label.text = newLabelString;
}];
```

Comment: pls what? sorry I'm a newbie. could you show me how to solve this?

Comment: oh okay but I found something else to solve the repeating error

Comment: look at this? could you help me with this? https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-async

Comment: and especially this https://parse.com/questions/error-handling-when-network-connection-fails

Comment: I would be glad if you could help me with this...I wanted to make something like: if theres an internet connection load the label and if not doesnt load the label.

Comment: But it seems to be one open problem...the first error with warn parseonoperation.....what do you mean by networking on the mainthred and wtf is the mainthread :D hahhaha sorry ....where I've to put you code?

Comment: basically this shows how to go async... and if parse fails newLabelString would be nil.

Comment: Oh I understand...okay and where to put this code? delegate? used controller.m? initialcontroller?